# How can I make a github action timeout if the runner isn't found?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have a github action that runs on multiple self-hosted runners, and it runs multiple times a day. As of now, if for any reason one of the runners is not found (i.e. the runner isn't currently running, for whatever reason), I want that job to fail, rather than continue to wait infinitely for that runner to be available.

I've tried the following code in my workflow, but timeout-minutes only seems to take effect *after* the runner has started:

```yaml
timeout-minutes: 15
runs-on: {matrix.runners}
```

is there some way to cause the job to fail if the runner isn't found after a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible at the the moment (3/2024). See [this discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50926) for details.

As a workaround, several users on the thread have created a solution for cancelling stuck jobs. This script can run in a separate scheduled workflow.

```
gh -R {owner}/{repo} run list -w cleanup.yml -s queued --json databaseId -q '.[].databaseId' | sort -nr | tail -n +2 | xargs -r -n 1 gh -R {owner}/{repo} run cancel
```

Replace `{owner}/{repo}` with your own repository.